# Measure of the set of convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I need some help to solve this exercise.
Let $a_n$ a sequence of real numbers such that $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $A$ the set
$$A:=\{x\in[0,2\pi]:\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n|\sin(nx)|<\infty\}$$
Suppose that $\mu(A)>0$. Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$$
Probably it's needed to use Riemann-Lebesgue theorem on Fourier transform, but i don't see how.

Comment: Sorry, it's $\sum<\infty$. A typo now fixed.

Comment: If $A$ contains at least one rational multiple $x$ of $\pi$, then $|\sin(nx)|$ will have a minimum value $k > 0$. Then $$k\sum_n a_n = \sum_n ka_n \le \sum_n a_n|sin(nx)| < \infty.$$ If $A$ doesn't contain a rational multiple of $\pi$, you can still approximate them.

Comment: Extend $A$ periodically to $A^*:=\{x\in\Bbb R:\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n|\sin(nx)|<\infty\}$. From the addition formula for the sine function it is clear that if $x\in A^*$ and $y\in A^*$ then $x-y\in A^*$. Because $\mu(A^*)>0$, the difference set $A^*-A^*$ contains a non-empty open interval, by a theorem of Steinhaus. Consequently $A^*$ also contains a non-empty open interval, as does $A$. It follows that $A$ contains a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Hi. Very brilliant.
Your argument can be generalized: If $A\leq (\mathbb{R},+)$ is an additive subgroup of the real line, such that $\mu(A)>0$, then $A=\mathbb{R}$.
Because it contains an interval centered in $0$ by Steinhaus, and then it's easy to verify that it covers all real numbers